# Showing $\{ \alpha _{i} \}$ forms a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> In a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$, assume $\alpha _{1} , \ldots , \alpha _{n}$ are linearly independent but that $\beta , \alpha _{1} , \ldots , \alpha _{n}$ are linearly dependent for each $\beta \in V$.
>   Prove that $\alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_{n}$ forms a basis of $V$.

Here's my attempt:

If $\alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_{n}$ forms a basis of $V$, then we are done. If not, let $\beta$ be any element in $V \setminus \text{Sp} \{ \alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_{n} \}$. Then $\alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_{n}, \beta$ would be linearly independent by the linear independence lemma. This contradicts our assumption. Thus, $\alpha_1 , \ldots , \alpha_{n}$ forms a basis of $V$.

Is this proof okay? This is a problem frm Katsumi Nomizu's Fundamentals of Linear Algebra.

Comment: It's OK.  More directly there exist scalars $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_n$ such that $c_0\beta + c_1\alpha_1 + \ldots c_n\alpha_n = 0$ where $\sum_{j=0}^n c_j^2 \neq 0$. We must have $c_0 \neq 0$ otherwise the $\alpha_j$s are dependent. So every $\beta \in V$ is a linear combination of the $\alpha_j$s.